# VueFire: Resolving references after setting on the client

Tags: firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, vuefire

According to the [docu](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vuefire) "[...] VueFire will automatically bind up to one nested references.". That works well, if I retrieve an object (map) from the database with a property being a `ref`: The `ref` gets ressolved automatically on the client (`ref_property` will not hold the path to the object (e.g. `users/123`) but the actual data (`{username: 'john', hometown: 'autumn'}`).

Question is: How do I update a `ref_property` (e.g. suppose a `last_edit_by_ref`) on the client in a way, that a.) VueFire is able to resolve this to a valid JSON for the UI and b.) make sure that it's stored as a ref in the database at the same time?

I tried to fetch the referenced object (again) from the collection as explained [here](https://vuefire.vuejs.org/vuexfire/writing-data.html#updates-to-collection-and-documents) ("To write a reference to a document, you pass the actual reference object"). The issue with this is however, that VueFire does not ressolve this, leading to empty values in the UI:

```
post.last_edit_by_ref = db.collection('users').doc('123')
```

Background: If I'm setting plain JSON, the property is no longer stored as a `reference` in the database. This is bad, since the linked object is likely to be changed (and the linking objekt would then hold copied, outdated data).

Answer (score 1):

It does not related to VueFire. It is how firebase parse the Object it get in the set/update methods.

If you focus on this part:

```
const data = {
  age: 18,
  name: "John",
  carRef: db.collection('cars').doc('john-car'),
}

await db.collection('users').doc('john').set(data);
```

You will have the ref in firestore. And in turn, VueFire will automatic bind the object.

For your case, i think you will need to find a way to get the `db.collection('users').doc(last_edit_user_id)` to make the ref for post.